# Entity Framework does not return object

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net

Hi I found problem with EF.

Here is my [Model](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?66091617f9.jpg)

I loaded asset:

```
POCO.Asset asset = _context.Assets.Where(a => a.UID == assetUid).First();
```

then I go through all properties

```
foreach (POCO.Property p in asset.Properties) /* request to db */ { /*...*/ }
```

categories:

```
foreach (POCO.Category p in > asset.Categories) /* request to db */ { /*...*/ }
```

related assets:

```
foreach (POCO.Relation relatedAsset in entityAsset.Relations) /* request to db */ { /*...*/ }
```

all navigation properties work fine. I can see request to db through profile. everything is good.

but if I go through Relations and trying to load RelatedAssetProperties then I have a problem.
Basically my Asset has 4 relations and each relation has 2-3 properties.

```
foreach (POCO.Relation relatedAsset in entityAsset.Relations) /* request to db */
{
 /**/
 ICollection<RelatedAssetProperty> rap = relatedAsset.RelatedAssetProperties;
 foreach (RelatedAssetProperty relatedAssetProperty in rap)  /* request to db */
 {
  /**/
 }

}
```

During RelatedAssetProperties execution I see all 4 requests to db to get properties. I run all requests in SQL manager and each returns data.

But for some reason only for first relation rap has items (RelatedAssetProperty). For other Relations it is empty.

And I do not know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you make sure that your entities have a primary key which makes sense ? [I had a similar problem in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111112/entity-framework-result-discrepancy-for-a-database-views) where only the first recordset in the DB was returned.