# Entity Framework. View return duplicate records

Tags: entity-framework, duplicates

I use Entity Framework that contains view. And I have query:

```
var data = this.context.vwRevenues
    .Where(x => x.revenue >= 0);
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.year)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.month)
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
```

This query returns set of entities, but 1st entity equals 5th.

```
data[0] == data[4] // true
```

I take sql script for this query from sql tracer and run it into SQL Management Studio,
it returns different records.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity framework result discrepancy for a database views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111112/entity-framework-result-discrepancy-for-a-database-views)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

As per **@Giovane** Answer's

**We had the same problem in our system with Entity Framework dealing with views. Try using ROW_NUMBER () OVER () SQL to create a column with unique values​​, but did not work.**

I did the same thing but to make it work i need to open the EDMX model and then select a this column as an **Entity Key.**

[image]

Then it will work

There is a very good article on this

[Duplicate Records](http://jepsonsblog.blogspot.in/2011/11/enitity-framework-duplicate-rows-in.html?showComment=1348809764880#c1389404724781617559)

The articles most important line is:

***When including a view in your Entity Model, the model seems to simply use the first not-nullable columns as primary key (as all columns used in the primary key should be non-nullable).***

Comment: What is meant by "the first not-nullable columns"? How many exactly? Certainly not all of them, or else I wouldn't have stumbled over the issue in a view without any non-nullable columns.

Comment: That was a sneaky little feature... Thank you for the great fix!

Comment: I just ran into this problem and BOOM! Thanks! You'd think EF would have predicted this by now

Comment: @jDave1984 In new EF6 i think we will not be able to add view with non nullable column at all.

Comment: The link pointed to by "Duplicate Records" is broken.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I was desparate for not finding the solution and I wasn't sure If I was doing something wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 72):

You only need to do: `context.viewname.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.ColumnName != null);`

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the AsNoTracking() tip, much easier to add than having to modify our entities for another ROW key :)

Comment: This worked for me. (And didn't remove some records where the EDMX update did.)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me too, where my view had no primary key field

Comment: OMG  -  ripping my hair out  ( figuratively)

Comment: Adding AsNoTracking removed duplicate in EF and haven't see any side effects of it, yet.

Comment: This worked very well in my situation - better than having to modify my entity.

Comment: I hope this thread is still active. Is there a solution for EntityFramework 4.1? It seems like version 4.1 doesn't have the option of AsNoTracking queries. Is there an equivalent solution for 4.1?

Comment: @Terence Version 4.3 [seems to have it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbquery-1.asnotracking?view=entity-framework-4.3.1g). There are no API docs for earlier versions on MS Docs. Is upgrading not an option?

Comment: Worked for me in EF 6

Answer (score 12):

We had the same problem in our system with Entity Framework dealing with views. Try using ROW_NUMBER () OVER () SQL to create a column with unique values​​, but did not work.

We need to insert a field more, an FK for another table in the view so that it could add as an additional training for mebro EntityKeyMembers Elimite and so the problem of repetition.

Thus, if the problem persists in this kind of situation, the solution is to insert a FK column for it to be MEMBERS of the fields that form the EntityKey of the table.

Comment: Read the answer of @Juan Carlos Sánchez Robles. ROW_NUMBER s a good way to go but wrap it with a ISNULL function

Answer (score 2):

In the view try converting the first record to a not null value, like this:

```
isnull(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "Column"), 0) AS Row
```

It indicates to the Entity Framework that can be the primary key automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to update edmx and set any key to column &&

if you don't want to update view record (only for get record) then use below code its working for me.

```
context.viewname.MergeOption = System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.NoTracking;

context.viewname.Where(x => x.columnname != null);
```

Comment: was hoping to not have to change edmx, but this regrettably did not work for me