# Why is ToList() changing my data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have the following data I pulling in a SQL View.

```
1   SH0032516   Dairy Farmers of America    100094  Capstone 4001 50lb              17500.00000000000000000000  ENTERPRISE
1   SH0032516   Dairy Farmers of America    106525  Capstone 4002 50lb              25000.00000000000000000000  ENTERPRISE
2   RE031159    MSDS/Ingredients Solutions  104508  Carrageenan WG-16   4000.00000000000000000000   ENTERPRISE
3   t101    Internal Transfer               100057  BI Ult Mus Pro Van 2lb 0.8oz    8448.00000000000000000000   ENTERPRISE
3   t101    Internal Transfer               105302  HB Q.M. Load CnC 3.3lb Cnd       400.00000000000000000000   ENTERPRISE
4   Pallets                                                                0.00000000000000000000   ENTERPRISE
5   OPEN                                                                   0.00000000000000000000   ENTERPRISE
6   OPEN                                                                   0.00000000000000000000   ENTERPRISE
7   OPEN                                                                   0.00000000000000000000   ENTERPRISE
8   SH0032513   Glanbia Foods Inc   S101066 Provon 290 15kg             8829.42300000000000000000   ENTERPRISE
9   OPEN                                                                   0.00000000000000000000   ENTERPRISE
10  OPEN                                                                   0.00000000000000000000   ENTERPRISE
```

Then in my MVC app, Controller, I have the following line of code:

`return View(await db.vwDockDoorDatas.ToListAsync());`

For some reason, the point of this question, the .ToList() is translating it incorrectly.  I get this after the .ToList()

```
1   SH0032516   Dairy Farmers of America    100094  Capstone 4001 50lb              17500.00000000000000000000  ENTERPRISE
1   SH0032516   Dairy Farmers of America    106525  Capstone 4002 50lb              25000.00000000000000000000  ENTERPRISE
2   RE031159    MSDS/Ingredients Solutions  104508  Carrageenan WG-16   4000.00000000000000000000   ENTERPRISE
3   t101    Internal Transfer               100057  BI Ult Mus Pro Van 2lb 0.8oz    8448.00000000000000000000   ENTERPRISE
3   t101    Internal Transfer               105302  HB Q.M. Load CnC 3.3lb Cnd       400.00000000000000000000   ENTERPRISE
4   Pallets                                                                0.00000000000000000000   ENTERPRISE
4   Pallets                                                                0.00000000000000000000   ENTERPRISE
4   Pallets                                                                0.00000000000000000000   ENTERPRISE
4   Pallets                                                                0.00000000000000000000   ENTERPRISE
8   SH0032513   Glanbia Foods Inc   S101066 Provon 290 15kg             8829.42300000000000000000   ENTERPRISE
4   Pallets                                                                0.00000000000000000000   ENTERPRISE
4  Pallets                                                                 0.00000000000000000000   ENTERPRISE
```

Comment: Is this Entity Framework?  What is the Entity Key(s) defined on the object?  A query that returns objects with the same Entity Key(s) would produce this behavior.

Comment: Ah, yes this is Entity Framework and there isn't an ID.  Thats my problem?

Comment: I doubt `ToList` is to blame here. Do you get a different result if you simply enumerate the result set?

Comment: As in `return View(db.vwDockDoorDatas.AsEnumerable<vwDockDoorData>());`? Yes... also, if I put a break point the SQL that is generated pulls the right info but if I look at the properties of the object it's like above.  Also, I'm also positive that **I** am to blame and not `ToList()` but figured no one would try and answer a question titled "I did something stupid again"... :)

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977920/entity-framework-view-return-duplicate-records

Comment: @MarkPeters Thanks, that was my problem.  Should I simply delete my question then, as a Duplicate?  I simply didn't know what to search under...

Comment: @RefractedPaladin You shouldn't delete it - I've voted for it to be closed as a duplicate, so that future searches for this question will lead to the right answer. :)