# Why is my linq query adding the same item to a list instead of all items?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am working on a project at work and am attempting to get all classes for a student from our database, however the same class keeps getting added to the list instead of all of the classes. I have practically the same query relating to another table which gets the classes of all professors, which for some reason works.

The entries in the database are not duplicates.

Here is the code I'm having issues with:

```cs
semester = "SP";
year = "19;
id = "0000001";
var tempCourses = (from b in db2.StuEnrolls where b.studentID == id && b.semester == semester && b.year == year orderby b.courseID select b).ToList();
```

I've also tried this:

```cs
var tempCourses = (from b in db2.StuEnrolls
                               where b.studentID == id && b.semester == semester && b.year == year
                               orderby b.courseID
                               select new StuEnrolls
                               {
                                   studentID = b.studentID,
                                   courseID = b.courseID,
                                   year = b.year,
                                   semester = b.semester,
                                   dept = b.dept,
                                   course = b.course,
                                   section = b.section,
                                   sectionTitle = b.sectionTitle,
                                   courseGrade = b.courseGrade,
                                   courseCredits = b.courseCredits
                               }).ToList();
```

Here is the similar code for professors that works:

```cs
var tempCourses = (from b in db2.CourseSectionsInstructor where b.instructorID == id orderby b.courseID select b).ToList();
```

As of now, I am getting 5 courses, all the same entry from the database. I should however be getting 5 unique entries. Here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FGED.png) of the output. The studentID has been edited out.

The DatabaseStructure looks like so:

```cs
    public partial class StuEnrolls
    {
        public string studentID_courseID
        {
            get
            {
                return studentID + " " + courseID;
            }
        }

        [Key]
        public string studentID { get; set; }

        public string courseID { get; set; }

        public string year { get; set; }

        public string semester { get; set; }

        public string dept { get; set; }

        public string course { get; set; }

        public string section { get; set; }

        public string sectionTitle { get; set; }

        public string courseGrade { get; set; }

        public decimal courseCredits { get; set; }
    }
```

The table in the database is made up of:
[Table Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBWjg.png)

Comment: Sounds like a data issue.  Have you verified that the database data is correct and that the SQL used to hydrate StuEnrolls doesn't have a bug?

Comment: The query looks fine. Can you post a snippet with some of the data in `StuEnrolls`?

Comment: Can you also show what's being passed? `id, semester and year`?

Comment: Have you used the debugger to verify the data? Nothing looks out of place here unless I'm missing something. Can you post sample data if it's coming over correctly?

Comment: What object/relational mapping framework are you using (sorry if I missed any telltale signs in your question)? And is `StuEnrolls` a view?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I am using ASP.NET-MVC5, where I load the data into the model, in this case db2. I work for a school, therefore I am obligated to keep students information as secure as possibly, so sharing results is a bit difficult.

Comment: @ChrisPetraskie: No issue with being unable to divulge student records (in fact, I'd suggest you set up a sample class with fantasy data, if anyhow possible, just for debugging). I was thinking of [quirks to be aware of when using Views with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977920/entity-framework-view-return-duplicate-records), and maybe something similar is going on here with the O/R framework you are using.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Databases are not my strong suit. I am actually a student employee at the school, so this is still a learning process for me. I'm unsure of how to explain what O/R framework I am using. We use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I am wondering if it has something to do with having two primary keys in the database, and only one in Visual Studio. I haven't encountered any problems until now, though.

Comment: @ChrisPetraskie: SQL Server Management Studio is an administration tool that lets you access a database. It is not integrated in your application. ASP.NET-MVC5 is a general development framework for web applications, but as far as I know, it does not bring the functionality to map database content to classes and vice-versa out of the box. That's where you are probably using an O/R framework such as [Entity Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Framework) or [NHibernate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate), as you mentioned you "load data into the model". Chances are the ...

Comment: ... reasons for the issue you are observing depend entirely on that O/R framework, so it would be helpful if you can find out which one it is. Maybe you can check the assemblies your project references to see which 3rd party tools you are using?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I understand now. We are using Entity Framework. I just can't seem to locate the issue, and am unsure where to even look at this point. If there is any more information I could provide, ask away and I'll do my best to supply it.

Comment: @ChrisPetraskie: Ok, my other question: Is `StuEnrolls` a *table* or a [*view*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL))?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have had something to do with the table having two primary keys, and the Database Structure only having one key.

This code seems to have fixed the issue:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<StuEnrolls>().HasKey(k => new { k.studentID, k.courseID });
}
```