# Not Getting Expected Results in foreach(var item in Model)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC5/C# Index View that will display all of an employees registered vehicles for the parking lot.

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
<table class="table">
<tr>
<td>                    
<b>Vehicle Make:</b> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.veh_make)
</td>
<td>
<b>Model:</b> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.veh_model)
</td>
</tr>
</table>
}
```

The Model is based off of a View that joins two SQL Tables.  Header (Table 1) and Vehicles (Table2).

The SQL View is a Left Outer Join, creating a result of the user Name/Header (1) to all of the vehicles associated to that user, in the Vehicle Table (Many).

I have two cars in the Vehicle Table.  When I Open the SQL View Where logon_id = {my id}, It shows two records in the results.  I see my BMW and Subaru.  And so, I believe that my SQL Join is correct?

But, when I duplicate this from my Controller, I don't get the expected results (2 different vehicles) on my MVC Index View.  Instead, I see the same vehicle listed twice.

I am hitting the View, from my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
string MyName  = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
id = ParseMe.ParseLogin(MyName);
Web_Parkinglot_Header_FullViewRepository oItem = new Web_Parkinglot_Header_FullViewRepository();
var item = oItem.GetbyLogon((string)id);
}
```

And The GetByLogon

```
public List<Web_Parkinglot_Header_FullView> GetbyLogon(string id)
{
return this.Context.Web_Parkinglot_Header_FullViews.Where(a => a.logon_id == id).ToList();
}
```

Adding my SQL Join, just in case I am missing something here:

```
SELECT dbo.Header.last_name, dbo.Header.logon_id, dbo.Vehicles.veh_make, dbo.Vehicles.veh_model
FROM dbo.Header LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Vehicles ON dbo.Header.logon_id = dbo.Vehicles.logon_id
```

When I manually run this in SQL Server Mgmt Studio, (where logon_id = m*y Id*), I see two rows with both of my individual cars.

Running this via my model code, I get the same vehicle twice.

Where I get lost in troubleshooting is that my SQL VIEW brings back both vehicles Where logon_id = my id.   So, why does my GetByLogon bring back the same vehicle twice, instead of two different vehicles.  What am I not understanding in my code?

Resolution:

```
return this.Context.Web_Parkinglot_Header_FullViews.AsNoTracking().Where(a => a.logon_id == id).ToList();
```

Thank you to TopSail for steering me in the right direction, with a link that referenced AsNoTracking().

This was the resolve to my issue and I am now seeing the expected results in my return.  Truth:  Although it works, I don't fully understand AsNoTracking(), and so I will still have some research to do.

Comment: I'm a little fuzzy to but maybe you don't want to foreach the item, but the items in the item. That is to say - item is a list. You want the items in the list. Not sure though - what is the actual return value of GetByLogon() when you provide an id that should have two cars?

Comment: To make this more clear maybe I should ask instead is Model something that has a  `List<Web_Parkinglot_Header_FullView>` as one of its properties, or is model actually just a `Web_Parkinglot_Header_FullView`? But yeah in the latter case no need to foreach, and in the former case seems to be not iterating the right thing.

Comment: What happens if, instead of calling DisplayFor, you just output `@item.veh_make`? Also, can you show the code from the point where you initialize `item` in your action to the point where it's passed in to the view?

Comment: @topsail - I put a debug stop to view the item, and to my surprise, it is bringing back 2 duplicate rows instead of the two unique rows.  That is puzzling to me because, the SQL View does not do that.  Also, I am using List(Web_Parkinglot_Header_FullView> in the model.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - When I remove Display For and just output (@item.veh_make) I see the same problem.  Duplicate Makes (Escalade x 2 instead of 1. Escalade 2. BMW).

Comment: `SELECT dbo.Header.last_name, dbo.Header.logon_id, dbo.Vehicles.veh_make, fbo.Vehicles.veh_model FROM dbo.Header LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Vehicles ON dbo.Header.logon_id = dbo.Header.logon_id` ... in this should query the join should be `on dbo.Header.logon_id = dbo.Vehicles.logon_id`

Comment: @topsail - thanks for the catch.  I updated the code.  The code was correct in my SQL View (the error was a typo, as I was removing many of the additional fields, for simplicity here).

Comment: well, sometimes back to basics - what is in the header table for logon_id = X and what is in the vehicles table for logon_id = X ? When you say you are looking at the sql view, are you running `select * from MyView where Logon_id = X;` ? Are the ids actually strings? Are you sure you're application is connected to the right database (dev, test, local, prod versions all may exist, etc.)

Comment: @Topsai - Let's say my logon_id = X.  In the Header Table, there is one record for logon_id = X.  It contains my name, work location, etc.   There are two records in Vehicles Table Where logon_id = x, because I have two cars.  When I say I am looking at the SQL View, I have done it two ways.  I have opened the View in design mode and simply added the Where logon_id = x.  And I have done it simply by doing Select from MyView where logon_id = X.  Both yield two distinct vehicles properly.  Just not sure why it repeats the first record in the Getbylogon().

Comment: - Additionally, there is currently only one SQL platform for this application.  Dev.  Therefore the connection string is correct.

Comment: Try assigning an object ID to one of the rows in the debugger? Are those two rows actually duplicates with the same data, or is the same in-memory object repeated twice in the list? I would be looking at your EF model: does it have a primary key on `logon_id`? That would make Entity Framework assume it can use the same object to represent any item that comes back with the same ID.

Comment: It might be interesting to run Context.Web_Parkinglot_Header_FullViews.ToList() with no where clause. You should probably check your DBContext to see if this object is really connected to the view you think it is connected to. Who knows - anything is possible.

Comment: @topsail, Okay.  I removed the Where clause and it brings back 5059 records.  The exact amount of records in the view.  So, that part looks as if we are hitting the View I am expecting.  But here is the fun part:  all 5059 records it brings back (mvc5 app - not straight SQL query) brings back 5059 duplicates of the very first record.  I feel like that is a clue, I just don't know the mystery .

Comment: To clarify, opening my SQL View inside SQL Server Mgmt Studio, I see 5059 unique records (without any where clause).  Hitting the View from my controller action, doing the same (no where clause) yields 5059 records that are all dup of first record in View Table

Comment: I feel like that is a clue too ... but I am also mystified :( This might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977920/entity-framework-view-return-duplicate-records

Comment: This seems like a concise summary of the above post: https://davecallan.com/duplicate-rows-entity-framework-querying-views/

Comment: @topsail, This previous post worked!  duplicate rows entity framework querying views.  AsNoTracking() was the answer.   ' return this.Context.Web_Parkinglot_Header_FullViews.AsNoTracking().Where(a => a.logon_id == id).ToList();'   Now, I need to spend some time reading up about 'AsNoTracking(), becuase although it resolved my issue, I don't fully understand why yet.     Thank you for all of your time and efforts helping me

Comment: Good - this was new material to me too so I also need to look into this some more.